# Create table in a mysql database

Tags: mysql, create-table

I'm trying to import a database and I have a mistake which says that I have a mistake near the last 1, where is my mistake?, I don't find it. Could you please help me?.

```
CREATE TABLE cluw.envios_service_desk (
id_envio_sd int(10) NOT NULL,
id_cuenta int(10),
id_usuario int(10),
enviado enum(1),
f_envio datetime,
tipo_envio enum(1),
PRIMARY KEY (id_envio_sd)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: If it is always set to be 1, why bother?

Answer (score 2):

enum deals with strings only

to fix it just add small quotes around them like this

```
CREATE TABLE cluw.envios_service_desk (
id_envio_sd int(10) NOT NULL,
id_cuenta int(10),
id_usuario int(10),
enviado enum('1'),
f_envio datetime,
tipo_envio enum('1'),
PRIMARY KEY (id_envio_sd)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```